# Where to put a PrintStream object to print a variable java

Tags: java, printing

I have a code that generates combinations and prints to screen, I'd like to print this to a file but Im not sure where to put my PrintStream object to have access to the String I'd like to print.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    brute("12345", 5, new StringBuffer());
}
static void brute(String input, int depth, StringBuffer output) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        System.out.println(output);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            output.append(input.charAt(i));
            brute(input, depth - 1, output);
            output.deleteCharAt(output.length() - 1); 
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I've been trying to put it everywehere, It seems to me like it should go after the for statement, perhaps I'm way off.

Comment: @Hovercraft's advice is good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `PrintStream` as one of the parameters for your `brute()` method and pass it along for the recursive call. Then in your main you just need:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
brute("12345", 5, new StringBuffer(), new PrintStream(fileOut));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a Static PrintWriter variable that your method writes to rather than the System.out.  Just be sure to close the variable in a finally block in your main method after calling your recursive method.